# ruby get param of current dir in url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm used to ruby with `params[:type]'`when trying to grab `?type=this` but is there a way to get `page` from `http://localhost:3000/admin/test/page`? Perhaps with a `params[0]` or something similar? Just need the name of the directory after test..

Comment: What does the corresponding section of your `config/routes.rb` file look like that processes that route?

Comment: showing us the `rake routes` output could have helped too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.url` and play with ruby to strip everything but the page.
Or you can define `admin/test/:id` in your routes.rb and manage the id within the controller.

Answer (score 1):

The /page will route to your method. So you should know what it is already.